# Setting Hibernate up in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hibernate

I have  a serious problem understanding how to set up hibernate using eclipse.
I spent like 2 days already and cant figure it out.
I downloaded Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, 128 MB.
Now I have no freaking Idea how to install hibernate!
I am also confused if i need maven (which made me waste like 5 hours).

Guys I am getting really sad please help me -.-!

I just want a javaproject where i can store objects in a database with hibernate ... not more ...

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to use Hibernate in your Java application, the only thing is add Hibernate's jar file in the class path and use it:

1. select your Java application.
2. click right button, choose "Properties".
3. select "Java Build Path" in the left frame, and click "Libraries" tab.
4. click "Add JARs" or "Add External JARs..." to add it.

You can use Hibernate API in your Java Application now.

Answer (score 0):

There are some hibernate tutorials here. it shows how to create hibernate application using eclipse IDE.
http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-tutorial/hibernate-tutorial.html